# How to change or camouflage address bar url?

Tags: javascript, information-hiding

We have a site dedicated to people suffering domestic violence. Our priority is for the people using the site to be safe and avoid them being caught by their "violentator".

Everything is almost sorted out but there is one thing that still doesn't keep the victim from being caught in the case the "violentator" takes a glance at the address bar.

What strategy do you suggest to hide the address bar or camouflage it with Javascript?

Thanks, Alvin

Comment: Unfortunately your options are mostly non-existent. The look and feel of most the browser window itself cannot be modified without the use of plug-ins or extensions that lie outside of the capabilities of running JavaScript in a web page. And all of this depends on the browser being used. What kind of information is the address bar displaying that you want to hide? Perhaps you could use URL rewriting, or load all content via AJAX ("single page app"), or other techniques to keep the URL clean.

Comment: Could you offer them a full-site disguise, complete with custom URL? For instance, upon visiting you present them with the option to "Choose a diguise." They pick from "News, Cooking, Technology, Gaming, etc." and you forward them to a new URL that fits that theme, while also having a custom escape screen that also fits the theme. Quick-escape brings up recent news, cooking tips, tech news, gaming cheats, and the URL itself backs up the testimony of the content. I hope you find a good solution - and thank you for the meaningful work in this area.

Comment: @Cory Thanks for your consideration! I suspected this. It's a bit unfortunate because there are situations in where it's needed, like this. Our website's url is "www.stopdomesticviolence.org" and the "domesticviolence" part is what is the most concerning for the case. I was hoping that there was some way to make the url look gibberish or something.

Comment: it's impossible to do exactly what you want, these people's suggestions are as close as it will come. I'd reccommend buying a few domains unrelated to domestic violence, like lasvegasnews.com or something, and they have the option to view the site on the alternate url instead

Comment: @sitavn Making the URL appear in gibberish would be leveraged by nearly every online hacker. It you can make it look like gibberish, not much prevents you from making it look like "paypal" either.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Right, that approach wouldn't be fruitful and maybe raise an eyebrow, which is not what we want. Your approach seems effectively good. Rather than camouflaging the page and the browser url, an impossible task, the escape key is used to redirect to the chosen page in a new tab, while the old tab is set to Google, avoiding the "dangerous" history to be recorded. I'm only concerned with the instant page switch, but I'm going to work on that to make it smooth. You're welcome, we should do more to make violated people know they're not alone!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of an iframe (which would visibly hide the iframe's src from the browser's address bar), and javascript's `location.replace` function to rewrite history as you navigate in that iframe. Combined with some of the other suggestions you should be able to mitigate some of the concerns you mentioned.